# OAuth authentication for clients with and without authenticating users

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have a .NET Core API that I've successfully created, having OAuth functionality.

I use `grant_type=password`, along with `username` and `password`, to receive an access token and call my controller actions using a request`Authorization` header and `AuthorizeAttribute`s with the `Policy` parameter on my controller actions. All is good.

However, there are a couple of scenarios that I'm not sure how to handle. For example:

Sometimes I want my client apps (there will be multiple) to allow access to the API when the user has not yet authenticated, but I don't want to leave it open to the world. That is, for some endpoints, a specific user doesn't need to be authenticated, but I want to restrict access. And then later, the user might choose to sign in, giving them access to more of the API based on their authorization.

How should I handle this? Should I pass along a `client_id` and `client_secret` with each request? And if so, how do I handle this in my AuthorizeAttributes? Or should I authenticate once using `client_id` and `client_secret` and a blank `username` and `password`....then again when/if the user actually signs in with all 4 parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the Resource Owner Password Grant - in case you have an end user - and the Client Credentials Grant - if you do not.

Depending on your API Gateway, this will behave a little differently, but it boils down to the following:

- The Client Credentials grant will only make sure that the backend knows which application is making the call, but without an end user context
- The Resource Owner Password Grant adds the end user context to this, but otherwise behaves similar to the CC grant in that you don't need a UI to implement it (in contrast to the Authorization Code Grant and the Implicit Grant).

Your API Gateway could for example, depending on the grant you use, add different headers to your backend, which you then can check to see what type of call is hitting it. For e.g. Mashape Kong, you will always get a `X-ConsumerId`, both for the CC and RO grants, but with the RO grant, you will additionally also receive a `X-Authenticated-UserId` (and `X-Authenticated-Scope`, if you work with scopes).

In case you are rolling your own OAuth2 implementation (ahem?), you would just need to introspect the token for the grant type used to create the token (`password` or `client_credentials`) to know what kind of access - as a machine user, or on behalf of an end user - you provide to the application.